# Handle CData in Stax and jaxb

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb

I'm trying to write a XML fragment containing a CData element in Spring StaxtItemWriter and Jaxb marshaller. But the output is either:

- not wrap with `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>`
- or escaped: `<` and `>` replaced by `&lt;` and `&gt;`

First, the item writer:

```
<bean id="userAuthorizationErrorItemWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
    <property name="rootTagName" value="UserAuthorizationEvent" />
    <property name="rootElementAttributes">
        <map>
            <entry key="xmlns:xsi" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="marshaller" ref="userAuthorizationTypeMarshaller" />
    <property name="overwriteOutput" value="true" />
    <property name="resource" value="file://C:/TEMP/fichierOUT.xml" />
    <property name="transactional" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Then the JAXB marshaller

```
<bean id="userAuthorizationTypeMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="contextPath" value="com.usecase1.xsd.model"/>
</bean>
```

The java class (simplified):

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "UserAuthorizationType", propOrder = {"action"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "UserAuthorization")
public class UserAuthorizationType {

    @XmlElement(name = "Action", required = true)
    protected String action;

    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    public void setAction(String value) {
        this.action = value;
    }
}
```

When writing to file, I want that the Action value to be encapsulate into a `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` block.

I tried using a `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter1.class)` that return:

```
public String marshal(String value) {
    return "<![CDATA[" + value + "]]>";
}
```

But the output is escaped:

```
<UserAuthorization><Action>&lt;![CDATA[first, second, third]]&gt;</Action></UserAuthorization>
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a custom XML marshaller and register the elements that should be output as CDATA. See if this example helps https://jaxb.java.net/faq/JaxbCDATASample.java